# Some Simple nasm Questions, I can't understand %n and selector

Tags: assembly, nasm

1.

```
%macro Descriptor 3
dw  %2 & 0FFFFh             
dw  %1 & 0FFFFh             
db  (%1 >> 16) & 0FFh           
dw  ((%2 >> 8) & 0F00h) | (%3 & 0F0FFh) 
db  (%1 >> 24) & 0FFh           
%endmacro ; 共 8 字节
```

I can't understand the meaning of % in the code

2.

```
DA_32       EQU 4000h
DA_C        EQU 98h
DA_DRW      EQU 92h

[SECTION .gdt]
LABEL_GDT:         Descriptor       0,                0, 0          
LABEL_DESC_CODE32: Descriptor       0, SegCode32Len - 1, DA_C + DA_32
LABEL_DESC_VIDEO:  Descriptor 0B8000h,           0ffffh, DA_DRW     


SelectorCode32      equ LABEL_DESC_CODE32   - LABEL_GDT
SelectorVideo       equ LABEL_DESC_VIDEO    - LABEL_GDT
```

what is the meaning and structure of SelectorVideo and SelectorCode32 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cann't understand the meaning of % in the code

The [NASM manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html) answer's that one:

> Preprocessor directives all begin with a % sign.

So, for example, `%macro` tells the preprocessor that you're starting a macro definition.

---

> what is the meaning and structure of SelectorVideo and SelectorCode32 ?

`SelectorCode32      equ LABEL_DESC_CODE32   - LABEL_GDT` simply creates an equate (kind of like a constant) and gives it a value that equals the distance from `LABEL_GDT` to `LABEL_DESC_CODE32`.

Comment: but ,what is the 'distance from LABEL_GDT to LABEL_DESC_CODE32'? could you say it a bit detailed?

Comment: By "distance" I mean the difference between the two labels' addresses.

Comment: are you sure it is just the difference ,,and the SelectorCode32 and SelectorVideo  are just numbers?

Comment: Labels are just a convenient way of naming addresses, and addresses are numbers. In NASM code you have to use square brackets (`[]`) to dereference the data at an address. But if you want to verify this you can do so by printing the value of `SelectorVideo` and `SelectorCode32`.

Comment: Thank you Michael ,would you please have a look at [this questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169003/what-does-this-descriptors-init-do)' commet