# What does this Descriptor's init do?

Tags: assembly, nasm

```
%macro Descriptor 3
dw  %2 & 0FFFFh             
dw  %1 & 0FFFFh             
db  (%1 >> 16) & 0FFh           
dw  ((%2 >> 8) & 0F00h) | (%3 & 0F0FFh) 
db  (%1 >> 24) & 0FFh           
%endmacro ; 

LABEL_DESC_DATA:   Descriptor    0,   DataLen-1, 92h
```

the things above are the definition.

here are the questions about its init:

```
xor eax, eax                           
mov ax, ds                              
shl eax, 4                              
add eax, LABEL_DATA                     
mov word [LABEL_DESC_DATA + 2], ax      ;what happens in this instruction?
shr eax, 16
mov byte [LABEL_DESC_DATA + 4], al
mov byte [LABEL_DESC_DATA + 7], ah
```

Comment: You really should start by learning x86 assembly before you try to analyze code snippets that you've found somewhere. If there's something about NASM's syntax that you're unsure about, you can almost always find the answer in [the manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc0.html), for example [section 3.3](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.3) which talks about effective addresses.

Comment: Knowing the layout of a "descriptor" would also help. I assume there's some "hardware reason" for it. It sure isn't to make things simple for the programmer! 16 bits of the "base" address go in one place, 8 bits in another, and the last 8 bits still another. Your code is converting a segment:offset address into a linear address (segment times 16 (<<4) plus offset), and stuffing the varios parts into their place in a descriptor. This looks like it might be for a .com file, where dos has chosen a segment (in `ds`) at runtime. Simpler if the load address is "known" at assemble-time.

Comment: ok I will buy a asm book first and read the answer here

Comment: do you know the meaning of `LABEL_DESC_DATA + 2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This macro initializes a Global Descriptor Table entry (i.e. a segment descriptor). Due to x86 architecture history these descriptors have some fields split in several parts:

[image]
(picture from [OS Dev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Global_Descriptor_Table))

The macro takes the base, limit and access values and puts them into corresponding places of the 8-byte entry.

The code fragment initializes the `Base` fields of the descriptor to their runtime values. Because `Base` must be a linear address, it calculates that address first by using the `linaddr = segment<<4 + offset` formula (valid for real mode).

For more info, see the OS Dev wiki: [Segmentation](http://wiki.osdev.org/Segmentation), [GDT](http://wiki.osdev.org/Global_Descriptor_Table).

Comment: do you know the meaning of `LABEL_DESC_DATA + 2`

Comment: It means "the address of `LABEL_DESC_DATA` plus 2 bytes. Since x86 is little-endian, it means it will point to the bit 16 of the descriptor, i.e. the field `Base 0:15` in the picture above.

Comment: But in NASM we use square brackets (`[]`) to dereference the data at an address.So what does the whole `[LABEL_DESC_DATA + 2]` mean?

Comment: Does `[LABEL_DESC_DATA + 2]` mean the data of the address  `LABEL_DESC_DATA + 2` ?